# Mistake in lease

Tags: residential-lease

There was a large error in my favor in a lease I signed and that was fully-executed.  In good faith, I have agreed to sign a new lease because I know what I agreed to pay.  I discovered this error in my lease when I went to pay my rent online for the month when the new lease goes into effect.  Someone in the management company at some point must have realized the error, created a new not fully-executed lease with a much larger but still incorrect amount, and entered that new amount in the system, overcharging me.  When I realized something was wrong with the rent amount, I contacted the office.  After numerous back and forths, I was told that I signed a lease with the second amount and they could not change a fully-executed lease.  Subsequently, I referred back to the actual fully-executed document which is in the system and I forwarded it to them. My question is - do I need to sign a document acknowledging that I am agreeing to void the old lease and if so what should that look like? Is there a name for a document like that? If signing a new lease is all I need to do, then that's great but I don't feel very good about this management company.

Comment: How large are the errors? If the original contract was for $12.00/month rent when it should have been $1200/month, there's a strong case that it's clearly a clerical error, so the $12.00/month rent would usually not be enforceable. But if the new contract is for $1250 when you say it should have been $1200, it's quite a bit murkier to argue the intent of the contract was not $1250. Do you have anything in writing about what the rent should be?

Comment: You just sign a new lease